# infimum for convex hulls and closures

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, supremum-and-infimum, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

For $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and a set $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ hold:
$$\inf\{\langle\alpha,a\rangle: a\in A\}=\inf\{\langle\alpha,a\rangle: a\in conv(A)\}=\inf\{\langle\alpha,a\rangle: a\in clo(conv(A))\}$$. By conv we mean convex hull and by clo closure. Why is this true and the infimums are equal?

Comment: I cant think of an example where this isnt $-\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the three sets be $S_1, S_2, S_3$ respectively. We immediately have $\inf S_1 \ge \inf S_2 \ge \inf S_3$ so it remains to check the two reverse inequalities.

**Hints:**

- For the first inequality, it suffices to show that for any $a' \in \text{conv}(A)$, there exists $a \in A$ such that $\langle \alpha, a \rangle \le \langle \alpha, a'\rangle$. (In plain words, going from $A$ to $\text{conv}(A)$ doesn't help make the inner product smaller.)
- For the second inequality, the idea is that any element of $\text{clo}(\text{conv}(A))$ can be approximated by an element of $\text{conv}(A)$. Since the function $a \mapsto \langle \alpha, a \rangle$ is continuous and linear, you can quantify how much this approximation affects the value of the inner product, and show that in the end it is negligible.

**Solution for the second inequality**

> Let $B = \text{conv}(A)$. We already know $(\inf S_3)$ is a lower bound for $S_2$ so it suffices to show it is the greatest lower bound. To do this, it suffices to show that for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$ we are able to find $a \in B$ such that $\langle \alpha, a \rangle \le (\inf S_3) + \epsilon$. To find such an $a$, consider $a' \in \text{clo}(B)$ such that $\langle \alpha, a' \rangle \le (\inf S_3) + \epsilon / 2$. Since $a'$ is in the closure of $B$, there exists $a \in B$ such that $\|a-a'\| < \frac{\epsilon}{2\|\alpha\|}$. Then, using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $$\langle \alpha, a\rangle = \langle \alpha, a' \rangle + \langle \alpha, a - 'a \rangle \le (\inf S_3) + \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \|\alpha\| \frac{\epsilon}{2\|\alpha\|} = (\inf S_3) + \epsilon.$$

**Solution for the first inequality**

> Any $a' \in \text{conv}(A)$ can be written as $c_1 a_1 + \cdots + c_n a_n$ for $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in A$ and $c_1, \ldots, c_n \ge 0$ summing to $1$. WLOG let $\langle \alpha, a_1 \rangle \ge \cdots \ge \langle \alpha, a_n \rangle$. Then $$\langle \alpha, a' \rangle = c_1 \langle \alpha, a_1 \rangle + \cdots + c_n \langle \alpha, a_n \rangle \ge \langle \alpha, a_n \rangle.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one more question $\inf S_{1}\ge \inf S_{2}\ge \inf S_{3}$ follows from $A\subset conv(A)\subset clo(conv(A))$?

Comment: @Laura Yes that's right

Comment: How does showing $\langle \alpha, a \rangle \le (\inf S_3) + \epsilon$ imply that $S_3$ is a lower bound for $S_2$? As far as I can tell this just shows that $S_2$ can be arbitrarily close to $S_3$.

Comment: @MONODA43 Sorry I wrote something incorrect, which I've fixed. We actually already know $\inf S_3$ is a lower bound; the goal is to show it is the greatest lower bound. Showing existence of $a$ such that $\langle \alpha, a \rangle \le (\inf S_3) + \epsilon$ suffices, since if for some $\epsilon$ this isn't possible, then you could obtain a larger lower bound. See Theorem 2 on [this page](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/epsilon-definition-of-the-supremum-and-infimum-of-a-bounded) for more detail.